# Using scss mixins with nextJs

Tags: sass, next.js, scss-mixins

I I've got the following next.config.js setup:

```
const path = require('path')
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true
})
module.exports = {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')]
    },
}
```

and I'm importing a global scss file using:

```
import '../styles/main.scss';
```

In this main.scss file, I'm using some mixins like:

```
@mixin wrapper() {
  ...
  @media screen and ($max-hd) {
    width: calc(100% - 6em);
  }
  @media screen and ($max-md) {
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
  }
}
```

where both max-hd and max-md are variables from another scss file:

```
$max-md: 'max-width: (#{$break-md - 1px})';
$max-hd: 'max-width: (#{$break-hd - 1px})';
```

If I use the variable ${max-hd} in as content in the same wrapper mixin, it prints the right value:

```
content: "max-width: (1739px)";
```

But the media queries seem to be completely ignored. I'm having a hard time debugging, as this is my first time with Next.js and I can't find the exported styles (google developer tools throws me back to the actual scss, which looks correct).

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OMG. The error was just parenthesis in the wrong place.
     `content: "max-width: (1739px)";`
The printed value was showing me all the time. It should be:
    `"max-width: 1739px";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I use scss with my next js project:

1. Install sass

```
npm install --save-dev sass
```

(or `npm i sass` if you compile your code on the server).

2. I created a root directory named scss, in it I have my variables, mixins etc. For example:

breakpoints.scss

```
$screen-sm-min: 640px;
$screen-md-min: 768px;
$screen-lg-min: 1024px;
$screen-xl-min: 1280px;

@mixin sm {
  @media (min-width: #{$screen-sm-min}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin md {
  @media (min-width: #{$screen-md-min}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin lg {
  @media (min-width: #{$screen-lg-min}) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin xl {
  @media (min-width: #{$screen-xl-min}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

3. Then I use scss modules like this:

**MyComponent.module.scss:**

```
@import '/scss/breakpoints';

.image {
  position: relative;
  

  @include lg {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

5. in my component, I import the styles and use them as described here: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/css-modules

There are more options here:
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/styling/sass

Comment: Hey, Tomer! Your setup is pretty good, and it actually helped me to see the (stupid) error I had.

Comment: This is ideally what I want, but I can't get it to work. Can you elaborate on " created a root directory named scss, in it I have my variables" - Where is this directory in relation to your `src/` directory?

Comment: I am using `app/` directory, but it is a sibling folder, not inside it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create file `./styles/_mixins.scss`
2. Update config `next.config.js`

```js
sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
    prependData: `@import "mixins";`,
},
```

compatible with version nextjs13

---

What worked for me in nextjs14

```
  sassOptions: {
    prependData: `@use "~/styles/mixins/mixins.scss";`,
  }
```